# What is the source: attribute of a tweet sent from a tweet button using the Twitter Search API?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to use Twitter search to find all mentions of a word that DIDN'T come from a "tweet this" button. I'm trying to build a stream of all brand mentions, but I don't want to sift through all of the retweets coming from our blog, which uses Twitter's button.

As a first step, I tried looking searching for all of the tweets that came from my personal account, filtering by `source:txt`. It showed all of the tweets I texted in. Then `source:web`. It showed all of the tweets I entered on twitter.com.

But then I tried searching with `source:twitterbutton`. Nothing. Then `source:tweetbutton`. Nothing. Same with `source:tweet button`. I tried searching through all of Twitter's documentation on the Tweet button to see what the `source:` attribute is, but couldn't find anything.

When I go through my stream of tweets without filtering for the source, I see some that say *via Tweet Button* so I know they exist, but I can't seem to find the right `source:` operator to find them automatically.

FYI: I'm using the [Twitter Search API Method](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search).

**Bonus points** to whoever can tell me how to *negate* a source (return everything EXCEPT that source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is Tweet Button. The correct way to search for it will be `source:tweet_button`. Searching by source is very unreliable though (especially for multiword sources). Filtering by source requires that you include a keyword so you can't search just by source.

To negate a source you add a `-` in front like this `google -source:web`.

**Update:** Multi-word sources are [now](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1473#c5) `_` (underscore) separated.

Comment: Try this search: http://search.twitter.com/search?q=bieber+source%3Atweetbutton No results for that is hard to believe. It seems to work for every other method of tweeting (`tweetmeme`, `tweetdeck`, etc) I just can't seem to find the right keyword that targets Twitter's tweet button...

Comment: Well it looks like it is just broken then. That is the correct way to search for it though. https://twitter.com/#!/twittersearch/statuses/13157027404

Comment: @Hartley Brody: Search now works with underscores: http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1473#c5

Answer (score -1):

I started tweeting with the fine folks over at Tweet Deck since their application lets you look for ones that came from the Tweet Button. It turns out I was only **one character away**. D'oh!

Use `source:tweet_button` to get only tweets from Tweet Buttons. And, as Abraham mentioned, all you need is a `-` before the parameter for it to negate that source. [Example search](http://search.twitter.com/search?q=bieber%20-source%3atweet_button).

Thanks for all the assistance! Especially from [@DesktopDeck](https://twitter.com/#!/DesktopDeck/status/57462797637918721)!